Where does capacitor matrix come from in meyer model?
The following is from FIRST ORDER QUASI STATIC MOSFET CHANNEL
CAPACITANCE MODEL.
The total gate charge \$Q_g\$ is a function of the terminal voltage under steady-state conditions.
The gate capacitances are found as:
$$C_{gs} = \frac{\partial Q_g}{\partial V_{gs}} \quad C_{gd} = \frac{\partial Q_g}{\partial V_{gd}} \quad C_{gb} = \frac{\partial Q_g}{\partial V_{gb}} \quad (2.1)$$
$$C_{gg} = C_{gs} + C_{gd} + C_{gb}$$
where \$V_{gs}\$, \$V_{gd}\$, and \$V_{gb}\$ are the gate-to-source, gate-to-drain, and gate-to-bulk voltages.
The drain-to-bulk, source-to-bulk, and drain-to-source capacitances are assumed to be zero.
$$C_{ds} = C_{db} = C_{sb} = 0$$
$$C_{sd} = C_{bd} = C_{bs} = 0$$
It is assumed that the capacitance matrix is symmetrical, which is necessary to conserve energy.}
$$C_{gd} = C_{dg} \qquad C_{gs} = C_{sg} \qquad C_{gb} = C_{bg}$$
The total source, drain and bulk capacitances are calculated as:
$$C_{dd} = C_{ds} + C_{dg} + C_{db}$$
$$C_{ss} = C_{sg} + C_{sd} + C_{sb}$$
$$C_{bb} = C_{bs} + C_{bd} + C_{bg}$$
These five assumptions give the capacitance matrix as shown below:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
C_{gd} + C_{gs} + C_{gb} & -C_{gd} & -C_{gs} & -C_{gb} \\
-C_{gd} & C_{gd} & 0 & 0 \\
-C_{gs} & 0 & C_{gs} & 0 \\
-C_{gb} & 0 & 0 & C_{gb}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I have no idea how the author derive this matrix from.
According to The Maxwell Capacitance Matrix, the Matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
C_{gg} + C_{gd} + C_{gs} + C_{gb} & -C_{gd} & -C_{gs} & -C_{gb} \\
-C_{dg} & C_{dg} + C_{dd} + C_{ds} + C_{db} & -C_{ds} & -C_{db} \\
-C_{sg} & -C_{sd} & C_{sg} + C_{sd} + C_{ss} + C_{sb}  & -C_{sb} \\
-C_{bg} & -C_{bd} & -C_{bs} & C_{bg} + C_{bd} + C_{bs} + C_{bb} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This can further simplified into
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
C_{gg} + C_{gd} + C_{gs} + C_{gb} & -C_{gd} & -C_{gs} & -C_{gb} \\
-C_{dg} & C_{dg} + C_{dd} + C_{ds} + C_{db} & 0 & 0 \\
-C_{sg} & 0 & C_{sg} + C_{sd} + C_{ss} + C_{sb}  & 0 \\
-C_{bg} & 0 & 0 & C_{bg} + C_{bd} + C_{bs} + C_{bb} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Q = CV or dQ = CdV, you have 4 terminals so 4x4 matrix.

@internet Take a look at my update

@kile  There is no possible charge function possible that can be differentiated to generate the Meyer capacitance model. Can't be done. And Spice depends upon differentiation to get from A to B. So that model cannot ever be made to comport with actual MOSFET behavior as it will always result in creating and destroying charge (which doesn't really happen.) This has never been fixed in Spice. Probably never will be. I'll look over your work in a day or two, though. I may or may not have anything to add. It is a hack.

@periblepsis  Do you mean it's an asuumption?

@kile No. I don't mean that. I mean it is a fiction. It "gets by" for some cases. But it's just piecewise fittings. See Meyer 1971 "MOS Models and Circuit Simulation" and Google Scholar listing citations (over 400!)

@kile Also, it may be worth reading through M. A. Cirit 1989 "The Meyer model revisited: why is charge not conserved?", doi:10.1109/43.39064. Perhaps look at Ward-Dutton 1978 and Yang-Chatterjee 1982 which are charge-based and were implemented in Spectre.
